# I can't get Facebook app settings right for a photo upload

Tags: facebook-graph-api, upload, vb6, photo, chilkat

I have a vb6 application that creates a jpg image.  I need to have the user click on a button to have that image uploaded to her Facebook page.  I created a Facebook app and use an api (chilkat) with my vb6 to do the upload.  But, I've really been stumbling around trying to get it working.  On the Facebook side, what settings should I have to just upload a photo?  For example, this runs on Windows PCs...  what platform do I designate in my Facebook app??

Also, my current attempts get an error from Facebook saying that "***Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains.***"  I expect this upload to be from the user's PC to Facebook.  What URL/domain do they want?

Are there samples of this type of thing that I could check?  Thanks -  John

New info as of Nov 12 --
I have the Facebook app set as a Website using "localhost" which seems to move me along a bit.  But, now I get the error --
   "***The request is invalid because the app is configured as a desktop app***"

Is that telling me my Facebook app is a desktop??... or that my vb6 code says it is a desktop?  If I have to change the Facebook platform, it looks like I need a Windows store id?  If so, is that just a simple registration (and $19)?  Thanks -  John

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/platforms: _“Alternatively, you can build a Login flow manually. This is for cases where you have an app that does not use our SDKs, such as native desktop apps, […]”_

Comment: Thanks.  I'll take a look, but am not sure I can get the Login to work the way I need.

Comment: It has to happen in some kind of webview/browsing component for desktop apps.

Comment: I created a new Facebook app to do the same function.  That one doesn't have the "desktop" error.  I am now getting a "bad param" error, which I will dig into now.  This question is no longer relevant.  Thanks!